# Right vs. Correct

Tags: synonyms

Is it correct to say "you are correct" if you want to inform somebody that they answered correctly?

I am not a native speaker, but I would always say "you are right". As I understand it, an answer can be correct, but if a person is correct you are referring to the manner in which he or she is conducting him-/herself. Am I completely off here? I am asking because I am frequently writing with a native speaker (in connection with an online quiz I run) and she often writes that I am correct. She is an English teacher an I generally believe her knowledge of the English language to be far superior to mine, but this bothers me and I hope someone will help me out here. :O)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, that sense can be found under [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/right), definition 2: *true or correct as a fact*. There are a few examples of how it can be used in a sentence under the definition (e.g.  **I'm not sure if I know the right answer**). So yes an answer can be "right". Saying "you are right" is a more idiomatic and friendly way of saying "you are correct". Both are used interchangeably, and accepted by native speakers.

Comment: Both "you are correct" and "you are right" are acceptable and equivalent in the context you are using them.  I (native speaker) tend to say "you are correct" because a) I an somewhat pretentious and b) it avoids potential confusion with other meanings of "right" (e.g., the opposite of left or conservative.)

"Correct" can be used to mean "proper" as in conduct or demeanor, but that's not terribly common these days and doesn't seem (sadly) to be applicable much.

Comment: Yes, you are completely off here, I'm afraid. Mind you, we've had this question before, a couple times in fact, so you're definitely not alone in being off. But you're off nonetheless. (And I've never thought about it before, but now that you mention it, I'm not even sure you can really blame it on your not being a non-native speaker, as in my mother tongue for example you can't use "correct" this way, either, yet it doesn't bother me one bit that it can be used that way in English. Alas, sometimes things just bother us at random, and all we can do is make our peace and let them go.)